Locating water supply for hot water
need to replace a tub shower cartridges to hot water side but don't know which yellow to shut off water.  outside on condo wall or inside connected to water heater.  everything's electric here.

The yellow on the hot water side will be warmer, assuming yellow is shut off valve.

The one on the outside should be the main(turns off all water).  Unless an older type, the main should be turned off, since quite a few(all?) newer ones are mixer valve type.

so the yellow handle shuts off entire water or just the top of water heater, which is the only valve that it has no other

They are probably both on the cold water side.  The tank needs cold water coming in to push hot water out, but the one at the tank will only turn off the hot water.

so that'll be fine to shut off instead of the outside one? well I get any water out

I'll see what happens , thanks
